Why is "could had" incorrect and "could have" correct?
I have recently realised that I have been wrongly using "could had" instead of "could have"
It just seems like a popularly accepted fact that "could" cannot be used with the past-perfect tense of a verb. But I have seen cases where that is possible, and in that case, at least to me, "had" makes more sense than "have"
Eg.

She could had finished earlier.

Or

She could have finished earlier.

I am not too well versed with english grammar to understand the difference. But even after a long discussion about this with a language model, I still feel like I am confused. Can someone please help me understand why "could had" is incorrect?
For context, here's the converstation I had with chatgpt trying to understand the difference.

'Have' in such constructions is the base form of the auxiliary 'have', not the present simple.  We don't say 'He will has finished'. The base form is used after all modals when followed by the past perfect: << I/you/she/we/they _ _ _ _ will/may/could/might/should/ought to... _ _ _ _ have finished/done/gone/made .... >>

The past perfect expresses the idea that something actually happened on a time-line; it took place in the past before another point-in-time in the past (The train had left before we arrived), whereas modal can/could expresses possibility or potential. The potential and the actual are antithetical. If we attempt to combine them, we end up with something that is neither fish nor fowl: *The train could had left before we arrived.  The present perfect, by contrast, is temporally amorphous and so it can be used of future, present, and past, and can combine with the modal.

To add to @EdwinAshworth 's point - a good test to see whether a bare infinitive being used (rather than simple present) is to try using the verb "to be".  You would say, "She could be finished earlier," but never "She could is finished earlier." That's how you know that "could" takes the bare infinitive and not the simple present.

"could had"  is not a verbal form in English, period. That AI thing should have told you that and if it didn't, it isn't any good.

ChatGPT does say that 'could had' is incorrect.

Because (in standard Englishes*) modals such as could always take the base form of the verb they govern - no exceptions.

could do; must eat; won't wait.

That base form can itself be another auxiliary, which will then be followed by the form that it requires:

could be done (passive); must have eaten (past); won't be waiting (progressive)

*I understand that in some dialects double modals are grammatical, though I've never heard them myself. I don't know whether "could had" is grammatical in any dialect or not.

Less educated southern AmE speakers say things like: might could, but I wouldn't even bother with that for an ELL.

The syntax of English grammar is -
Subject + modal auxiliary + base form of the verb + extension

She could have finished earlier.

Here, could have represents the sense of past unreal. For example-

If I had started my job last year, I could have payed all the debts earlier.

Modals always take a verb in base form and have is that base form.
